# Part of my code isn't accessed nor executed

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

A part of my form **Load Event** is neither accessed (breakpoint is not executed) nor executed (message box not showing), this is my code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open .ODI file";
        ofd.Filter = "ODI Files (*.odi)|*odi";
        DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        MessageBox.Show("bla");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName) + "\\VOL1.DAT", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        //------------------------CODE IS NOT EXECUTED AFTER THIS
        MessageBox.Show("bla2");
        //getting the Main Folders
        byte[] fldrn = new byte[4]; 
        fs.Position = 0x74;
        fs.Read(fldrn, 0, 4);
        int fldrnum = BitConverter.ToInt32(fldrn, 0);
        MessageBox.Show(fldrnum.ToString(), "1");

        byte[] namaes = new byte[28];
        foldernames = new string[fldrnum];
        for (int i = 0; i < fldrnum; i++)
        {
            fs.Position = 0x88 + i*4;
            fs.Position = 0x74;
            fs.Read(fldrn, 0, 4);
            int fldrnam = BitConverter.ToInt32(fldrn, 0);
            int pos = (int)fs.Position;

            fs.Position = pos + fldrnam;
            fs.Read(namaes, 0, 28);
            foldernames[i] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(namaes).Split('\0')[0];
            MessageBox.Show(foldernames[i], i.ToString());
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(foldernames[i]).ImageIndex = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you attach the event handler?

Comment: and it throws any exception or not..?

Comment: @cHao it's a new project this was my first time debugging, so i think it auto genrates it no ?

Comment: Did you run this code on a 64bit system? Are you sure the file VOL1.DAT exists in the specified folder?

Comment: @rummykhan no exception.

Comment: youre using which IDE.. and ys it automatically generate that code in the desingner side..

Comment: @Steve it does exist, it would have thrown an exception if it wasn't

Comment: No Form.Load event and exceptions on 64bit system doesn't work very well togheter

Comment: and does form loads.. without executing ur code.. or it does not load

Comment: @rummykhan i use Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Does it block on opening your FileStream? Or does your application close? Or do you supress any exceptions in the UnHandledExceptionEventHandler?

Comment: @Silvermind there is one thing i found weird, usually when debugging the debugged application comes on top of my VS window, but this one just starts minimized

Comment: Try your code without using VIsual Studio and see if throws an exception

Comment: jux remove the return; bro and see..

Comment: i removed the second FileStream and now it works, but this si weird, the file exists, why would it not execute ?

Comment: the file is placed in the same directory or not..?

Comment: it is in the same directory

Comment: mean where the exe file is located..?

Comment: u can change the file position to D:\\vol.dat
and than try.. u will b sure.. this is my practice..

Comment: ooh it's not in the same directory AS the exe, obviously im getting it from another directory.

Comment: hope your problem is resolved..

Comment: Can you tell me why you are trying to open a file (fs1) that you don't use anywhere in the remainder of the code above? What is the name of the file opened using ofd.Filename?

Comment: ok, i'll explain everything, so the fs opened files is a bunch of information, that i will use to extract files from fs1 opened file, fs1 is opening a package of files.

Comment: Problem solved, seems that if the file was already opened somewhere else(in mad edit), it stops the execution(???) of the code after FileStreaming that file.

Comment: If you had listened and tryed to execute your program outside of VS2010 you have seen your exception.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a/4934010#4934010

Comment: Thank you guys,@Steve put the solution so i can check it, also is there anyway to bypass this stupid limit ?

Comment: It is a duplicate then, try to move your code in the form constructor if possible. (or in the Form_Shown event)

Comment: @Steve alright, thank you, how do i delete this then ?

Comment: I think you could add an answer by yourself, explaining what happen and how you have resolved the problem. Put a link to the answer from Mr HansPassant and finally accept it to close the question. See you again on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, i was accessing a file already in use by one of my windows processes(fs1),  it didn't throw an exception though, this is by far explained in this answer: [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a/4934010#4934010)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have something like this in your constructor?  Would be best to have this in the designer file if it is windows forms.

`this.Load += new EventHandler( Form1_Load);`

Comment: i think thix is a window form app.. so that code must b generated in designer class..

Comment: @rummykhan that would be the best place for it to be but it wold work in a constructor.  I was just trying to identify if attaching the event was the problem.

Comment: @Omarrrio: For future reference, pictures of code are next to useless for most purposes.  Most people would very much prefer if you post code on a site like http://pastebin.com or http://ideone.com (or, even better, if you simply add it to the question so future visitors don't have to ask about it again).

Comment: @cHao, thank you and sorry, i won't let it happen again.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open .ODI file";
        ofd.Filter = "ODI Files (*.odi)|*odi";
        DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            //return;   jux remove this return and ur code will work fine
            // actually we dont use return in the body of if condition.. bad practice

        MessageBox.Show("bla");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName) + "\\VOL1.DAT", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        //------------------------CODE IS NOT EXECUTED AFTER THIS
        MessageBox.Show("bla2");
        //getting the Main Folders
        byte[] fldrn = new byte[4]; 
        fs.Position = 0x74;
        fs.Read(fldrn, 0, 4);
        int fldrnum = BitConverter.ToInt32(fldrn, 0);
        MessageBox.Show(fldrnum.ToString(), "1");

        byte[] namaes = new byte[28];
        foldernames = new string[fldrnum];
        for (int i = 0; i < fldrnum; i++)
        {
            fs.Position = 0x88 + i*4;
            fs.Position = 0x74;
            fs.Read(fldrn, 0, 4);
            int fldrnam = BitConverter.ToInt32(fldrn, 0);
            int pos = (int)fs.Position;

            fs.Position = pos + fldrnam;
            fs.Read(namaes, 0, 28);
            foldernames[i] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(namaes).Split('\0')[0];
            MessageBox.Show(foldernames[i], i.ToString());
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(foldernames[i]).ImageIndex = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, but when i remove the fs1 filestream, it works

Comment: _actually we dont use return in the body of if condition.. bad practice_ That is ridiculous.

Comment: well it's not bad practice, it makes sure the code is NOT executed if the cancel button is pressed

Comment: Of course you understand that I mean that it is ridiculous to say that it is bad practice. It is just an eager return. Put it between braces and it is clear as day what is happening.